# Easiest way to load table dump into database

Tags: mysql, database, load

I have a 71GB file having contents of one table of mysql database. 
Loading that takes me couple of days. Is there a easier way to load the data. 
I am not sure if removing indexes or splitting files actually helps.

How stackoverflower's solve this problem.

Comment: What is the file format - is this a MySQLDump file?

Comment: Its a bunch of mysql insert statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LOAD DATA` command. More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing the indexes? Is the dump using extended inserts?

Instead of removing you can also disable indexes: ALTER TABLE foo DISABLE KEYS; and re-enable with ALTER TABLE foo ENABLE KEYS;

If you can control the data getting dumped another good option is to export to a CSV file. MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE is faster than loading a SQL dump.

Comment: Initially dump had only inserts..and running db < .sql file gave me too many commands error. Then I added begin; and commit; at the start and the end.

Answer (score 1):

In the shell:

```
mysql dbname < dbname.sql
```

Comment: I am currently using this. Loooking for better ways.